# php convert Array to json and then parsing json

Tags: php, json

I want convert an array to json

```
<?php
   $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Result:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Now I want call value of 'a'.

```
$value = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
echo $value->a;
```

It no print anything.

So I try convert it to object:

```
 <?php
       $value = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5};
       $value = json_encode($arr);
       $value = json_decode($arr);
       echo $value->a;

    ?>
```

It no print anything too.

can please tell me my mistake?

Comment: In your last code snipped, you already have a json string - you don't have to json_encode it again - just decoding is enough. You Just have to put single quotes around it (the json string).

Comment: use error_reporting. `$value = {...}` is a syntax error... (It is a valid Javascript object, but you are in php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$json = json_encode($arr);
$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json->a;
?>
```

**Demo:** http://ideone.com/MkWWdA